# Open resource from inside the bundle using c++ / qt

Tags: macos, applications, filesystem, resources

I have a Qt app set as a bundle, and it requires a resources database. If I place it inside the bundle, how do I open it ?

The app was created in Windows, and in Windows and Linux, I can use the path for the database:

```
fopen(path, r);
```

I can do the same thing in Os X with a path like "`/Users/Me/Company/Product/resources.db`" or "`/Library/Application Support/Compay/Product/resources.db`"

1) What path would I use for the resources.db if I want to place the database in `Contents/Resources` ?

2) Would I be able to do anything to access the location using an Open File Dialog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being that the app structure in OSX is flat it should not matter where you put anything, other than for your own organization purposes.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out that you are technically correct, after I was able to get an absolute path to the Contents/Resources folder.